# Convert response to a string

Tags: json, response

I receive the following response from JSON.

```
{"Account":"{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Account\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aUbQQAU\"},\"FieldId__c\":\"0010I00002L0WNiQAN\",\"Id\":\"0014T000005aUbQQAU\"}"}
```

If I would want to convert this to a string,

```
String myJson = '{"Account":{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0014T000005aUbQQAU"},"FieldId__c":"0010I00002L0WNiQAN","Id":"0014T000005aUbQQAU"}}';
```

How do I convert this so I can use it in the statement -

```
Map<String,Object> mapresp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(myJson);
```

Answer (score 4):

This JSON is mangled: you have a single outer key, `Account`, whose value is not more JSON but a string value containing escaped JSON.

It would be best to fix this at the source of this JSON by correcting its logic. However, assuming this value is stored in a `Map<String, Object> inputJSON`, you can just deserialize the value of the `Account` property:

```
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(
    (String)inputJSON.get('Account')
);
```

Comment: this is the code that is sending this response. Is being received as Map<String,String>                                                                                          Map<String, String> tosend = new Map<String,String>();
for(Account objAccount :[SELECT FieldId__c,Id FROM Account WHERE Id=:acc.Id]){
tosend.put('Account',JSON.serialize(objAccount));
}

In return, I get the response as what is stated above. 
If I do convert the response to a string, then I should be able to navigate to FieldId__c. But how do I convert the response to a string?

Comment: `tosend.put('Account',JSON.serialize(objAccount));`: this is the source of your issue. You should not be serializing the material here; instead, allow the system to perform the required JSON serialization from the data structure you prepare.

Comment: Hi David, I don't think I understand that. So, I am trying to send this information to Org2 from Org1 and the return type is map<string,string>. The response body is what I got in Org2. If I do not serialize the request to be sent, how else will it be sent?

Comment: You could potentially change the return type to `Map<String, Object>`, or use a concrete Apex class that the system can serialize for you. There's lots of examples on SFSE.